# Variable "entry" does not exist in template at Structure Section

Tags: craft2

So, the subject.
I am currently working with customer of craftcms v2.
I am setting up Structure Section where I want to add Entry Type for index listing of items and add some items in list.

So, here is my setup:

1. Section: https://i.stack.imgur.com/quVtb.jpg
2. Section EntryType: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCglJ.jpg
3. Field Settings tab: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCC8I.jpg
4. Field Layout tab: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xK4QY.jpg
5. Entry Example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/K0GFw.jpg

I have 3 Entries added.
I made this setup exactly the same as was for same page type (Structure Section too). But page I did throws error as in subject title.

I've googled and found that the key for 'entry' object in template using is to check this option in Section settings:

'Entries in this section have their own URLs'

I found that in this article: https://straightupcraft.com/articles/the-craft-entry-variable

So, what may be the problem? This option is checked. Also exactly the same page (called Features) works well! It's kind of magic I think.

Simple code in template raises the error: https://pastebin.com/fjqeb1LT
I am using template in 'app/craft/templates/reviews/index.twig' folder.

Comment: Can you paste the complete code from index.twig where the "entry" is created?

Comment: What URL are you going to when you get this error?

Comment: @phaetons yes, here it is: https://pastebin.com/CH6RgGpC

Comment: @BrandonKelly url is http://localhost/reviews

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That `entry` variable will only be predefined for the template when you go to one of your entry’s URLs.

Your section’s Entry URL Format for top-level entries is `{slug}`, and your entry’s slug is `qweasdzxc`, so that would make your entry’s URL `<site-url>/qweasdzxc` (http://localhost/qweasdzxc).

If you change your section’s top-level Entry URL Format to `reviews/{slug}` instead of just `{slug}`, then the entry’s URL will become `<site-url>/reviews/qweasdzxc`.

When you go to `<site-url>/reviews`, you’re just accessing the `reviews/index.twig` template directly, so the `entry` variable was never defined, which is causing the error you’re getting.

Comment: Thanks! Strange but I saw calls and selections from entry variable from index.twig template (related to similair section) from other devs, so I was confused.